# UIButton and UIImageView Holding on to memory

Tags: xcode, memory, uiimage

iOS7 Xcode5.0.1

I have found loads of programatic answers to my question that will follow but no one seems to have an answer for why this happens when you don't even write code to reproduce the issue...

I have an app with two VC's. Bothe have custom buttons with images (png's) for active disabled and selected so no need for text.  Each VC has a background by using a UIImageView.  I like each VC via a Modal from one of the buttons, ALL done in the storyBoard so please remember this!

Now comes the issue...

After moving between the VC's via the buttons I then have a crash due to memory failure!

what seems to happen is that for each VC the button and background images NEVER get deallocated from memory!  Now again please remember there is no code that I have written to cache the images or what ever!  I have even then created a viewDidDisappear method which sets all outlets to nil but this doesn't help!  I can't believe that StoryBoard does this with button images and there has to be a simple way to dealloc these images.

Here is what Instruments calls it:  Category: VM: ImageIO_PNG_Data Responsible library: ImageIO Responsible caller: ImageIO_Malloc.

There is no leaks, the images are exactly the size they should be i.e. for the background of the device etc...

I have trolled through the internet for about a week and there is not one explanation, lots of 'hay your using setImage which caches the images' but nothing that explains this!

Any ideas would be welcome.  I can't post code as there isn't any, its all in storyboard...

Answer (score 1):

I suffered a lot with this issue only to find out that that some of my PNGs were corrupted.
Check the images you are loading, one or more can be the issue.